# timeval variable declaration in linux

Tags: c++, declaration, timeval

I am using timeval structure in order to get current system time. Normally if I declare it like that:

```
timeval curtime;
```

it is working. However I saw some code where people declare it as:

```
struct timeval curtime;
```

Is there any difference between these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, you must use `struct` prefix when declaring a variable with a struct type.

In C++, it's not required to prefix with `struct`.

Since you have tagged this as a C++ question, I assume you are using a C++ compiler and so you do not get a compiler error when you use `timeval` without the `struct` prefix.  However, if you were to use a C compiler, it would issue an error.